# "Freeze Panes" disabled Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

"Freeze Panes" feature on the "View" tab disabled. I checked all the recommended fixes:

- **don't** use "Page Layout" workbook view
- reboot (yes, the #1 Google result on a '"freeze panes" disabled' search recommended that)
- make sure "protect workbook structure" is **disabled** (it **wasn't** for me, but all recommended ways to turn this off for my workbook wouldn't work)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by moving all my workbook tabs individually to a new workbook, and then re-saving the new workbook under the same name.